# Ruby error to define Header

Tags: html, ruby

I'm trying to send a POST HTTP, but I'm receiving this error:

```
Response 400 Bad Request: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>

<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>

<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>

</BODY></HTML>
```

This is the part of my code sending the request:

```
//Header with authentication code
@header = {'Authorization' =>  @authentication_hash}
@http = Net::HTTP.new(@uri.host, @uri.port)
@req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(@uri.path, @header)
@req.body = "[ #{@dataJ} ]"
@res = @http.request(@req)
puts "Response #{@res.code} #{@res.message}: #{@res.body}"
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Instead of using Net::HTTP, which is like digging a pool with a shovel, I'd recommend using [HTTPclient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient) or [RESTclient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client). They're higher level and should get you where you want to be a lot faster.

Comment: Hi Tin Man, I Try use RestClient and my return was: `code`C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:48:in `return!': 400 Bad Request (RestClient::BadRequest) `code` follow my code: `code`  RestClient.post 'http://api.koin.net.br/V1/TransactionService.svc/Request', @data.to_json, :content_type => :json, :charset => :utf8, :accept => :json, :Authorization => @authorization_hash `code`